# JasperReport - Problemas al Recorrer lista

Tags: java, lista, jasper-reports, jasper

Estoy generando un informe a traves de JasperReport, pero estoy teniendo un problema particular con una lista, el cual para determinados datos me  pisa los valores repitiendo el valor de la ultima ocurrencia.

SubDataSet los valores que me imprimen de manera incorrecta en este caso es :

```
isTaskUsuallyPerInjured<p>
```

---

```
<subDataset name="PersonalAccidentDataset" uuid="ef68c793-2071-4e0e-9b26-99935588c08b">
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="nameOfMedicalServiceThatPayAtention" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="amputationName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="injuredPart" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="isTaskUsuallyPerInjured" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="isPolicyInterventionPerInjured" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="isHadSomeAmputation" class="java.lang.Boolean"/>
    <field name="personInsured" class="com.sysone.model.policy.PersonInsured"/>
    <field name="injuredType" class="com.sysone.model.claim.InjuryType"/>
</subDataset>
```

**Lista**

```
<componentElement>
    <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="50" width="500" height="200" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" uuid="faa55e29-96f0-47db-9039-6943ce41131e"/>
    <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
        <datasetRun subDataset="PersonalAccidentDataset" uuid="f918a670-2e68-4454-b093-f468fc370594">
            <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{personalAccidents})]]></dataSourceExpression>
        </datasetRun>
        <jr:listContents height="200" width="500">
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="70" y="29" width="150" height="14" uuid="94165ae0-e807-490f-8737-29d65e0d74f1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <box rightPadding="2">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personInsured}.getPerson().getLastName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="29" width="60" height="14" uuid="cc5e1f82-72cd-4cff-bdb3-1816808479cb"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Apellido:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="10" y="22" width="490" height="1" uuid="8fcb1a87-2fb6-4ac8-bb2d-0af9904b03d2"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="10" y="9" width="197" height="14" uuid="1936d56e-0f81-482e-9718-6024da8039b0"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["PERSONA ACCIDENTADA (" + $V{REPORT_COUNT} + ")"]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="285" y="30" width="190" height="14" uuid="b3c418c7-3db6-4c63-be4f-19daffbcdd5c"/>
                <box rightPadding="2">
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement>
                    <font isUnderline="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personInsured}.getPerson().getFirstName()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="225" y="30" width="60" height="14" uuid="596c717f-49d8-400b-b15f-5434af089a5a"/>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font isStrikeThrough="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Nombre/s:]]></text>
            </staticText>

            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-189" positionType="Float" x="10" y="85" width="60" height="15" uuid="d1b796ff-b570-42a3-a38a-459da885cde5"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Nac.:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-58" positionType="Float" x="73" y="85" width="127" height="14" uuid="02950676-0c60-4fa5-a0ee-a1405549077a"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="10" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{personInsured}.getPerson().getBirthDate()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-189" positionType="Float" x="10" y="108" width="87" height="15" uuid="500e2723-dea1-4cee-b471-22207418be6c"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Tipo de lesiÃ³n:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField pattern="dd/MM/yyyy" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement key="textField-58" positionType="Float" x="110" y="109" width="102" height="14" uuid="c7c53444-98eb-493c-8fd5-b1cbdd995cc9"/>
                <box>
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="10" isItalic="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{injuredType}.getDescription()]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement key="staticText-129" positionType="Float" x="10" y="130" width="204" height="14" uuid="bdf4f164-c5d0-4770-a021-483da5d58d0b"/>
                <box>
                    <topPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <leftPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <bottomPen lineWidth="0.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
                    <rightPen lineWidth="0.0" lineStyle="Solid" lineColor="#000000"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Bottom">
                    <font size="10" isBold="false" pdfFontName="Helvetica"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[¿Se encontraba realizando tareas laborales?]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement x="222" y="129" width="14" height="14" uuid="6a447844-f075-4212-834d-80341eae44d0"/>
                <textField evaluationTime="Report" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                    <reportElement key="textField-100" positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="14" height="14" uuid="ab04168c-2fc8-40fd-a2a2-bd817b02770c">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <box>
                        <pen lineWidth="0.75" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                        <topPen lineWidth="0.75" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                        <leftPen lineWidth="0.75" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                        <bottomPen lineWidth="0.75" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                        <rightPen lineWidth="0.75" lineStyle="Solid"/>
                    </box>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="10"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[($F{isTaskUsuallyPerInjured} ? "X" : "")]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
        </jr:listContents>
    </jr:list>
</componentElement>
```